# What was used to draw the rope?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I came across the following to draw a rope connecting two points. Is this a custom-made object, or is this something that came from a package?

If it is custom-made, what is the best way of constructing something like this without the code being overly convoluted?

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that this was drawn with TikZ?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a package, font, tool, book or other off-site resource** are off-topic as they usually do not revolve around an abstract issue.  Instead, [describe the problem](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and what has been done so far to solve it or, if applicable, ask on [Software Recommendations SX](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question. The question itself may not show any effort, but the answer is great and useful for many things. It would be a waste to hide it under a question put on hold.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is not too difficult to draw something along these lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[decorate,decoration={markings,
    mark=between positions 2mm and \pgfdecoratedpathlength-2mm step 2mm
      with
      {
        \draw[ultra thick,gray] 
        (-3.5mm,-1.25mm) to[out=0,in=160] (-2mm,-1.25mm) to[out=-20,in=160] 
        (2mm,1.25mm) to[out=-20,in=180] (3.5mm,1.25mm);
      }}] 
    (0,0) -- (4,-4);
    \fill (0,0) circle (3mm);   
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An arguably cleaner way is to do it with decorations.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations} %  decorations.text just 4 fun

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
    rope width/.store in=\RopeWidth,
    rope width=5pt,
    rope step/.store in=\RopeStep,
    rope step=2mm,
}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{rope}{initial}
{% 
\state{initial}[width=\RopeStep,next state=cont] {
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-\RopeWidth/2}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint{5*\RopeStep/6}{0.25*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{7*\RopeStep/6}{0.45*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{1.5*\RopeStep}{\RopeWidth/2}}
     \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint{10*\RopeStep/6}{0.55*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{11*\RopeStep/6}{0.6*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{13.5*\RopeStep/6}{\RopeWidth/2}}
    \pgfcoordinate{lastup}{\pgfpoint{-1.5*\RopeStep/6}{-\RopeWidth/2}}
  }
  \state{cont}[width=\RopeStep]{ 
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{lastup}{center}}
     \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint{-5*\RopeStep/6}{-0.6*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{-4*\RopeStep/6}{-0.55*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{-3*\RopeStep/6}{-0.55*\RopeWidth}}
     \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint{-\RopeStep/6}{-0.45*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{\RopeStep/6}{-0.25*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{3*\RopeStep/6}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint{5*\RopeStep/6}{0.25*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{7*\RopeStep/6}{0.45*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{9*\RopeStep/6}{\RopeWidth/2}}
     \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint{10*\RopeStep/6}{0.55*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{11*\RopeStep/6}{0.6*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{13.5*\RopeStep/6}{\RopeWidth/2}}
    \pgfcoordinate{lastup}{\pgfpoint{-1.5*\RopeStep/6}{-\RopeWidth/2}}
  }
  \state{final}[width=5pt]
  {
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{lastup}{center}}
     \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint{-5*\RopeStep/6}{-0.6*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{-4*\RopeStep/6}{-0.55*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{-0.5*\RopeStep}{-0.55*\RopeWidth}}
     \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint{-\RopeStep/6}{-0.45*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{\RopeStep/6}{-0.25*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{0.5*\RopeStep}{0pt}}
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=rope]
  \draw[red,thick,decorate,rope width=8pt] (-4,0) to[out=0,in=90] (0,-4);
  \draw[gray,thick,decorate] (0,0) to (4,-4);
  \draw[blue,ultra thick,decorate,rope width=8pt] (4,0) to (8,-4);
  \fill (-4,0) circle (8pt) (0,0) circle (8pt) (4,0) circle (8pt);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

All these decorations leave some room for improvement, in particular the one along the curved path has small gaps.

**ADDENDUM**: Here is a version that does not leave gaps. Yet it does not look too good when the curvature is large.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations} %  decorations.text just 4 fun
\newcounter{ropept}
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
    rope width/.store in=\RopeWidth,
    rope width=5pt,
    rope step/.store in=\RopeStep,
    rope step=2mm,
}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{rope}{initial}
{% 
\state{initial}[width=\RopeStep,next state=cont] {
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-\RopeWidth/2}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint{5*\RopeStep/6}{0.25*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{7*\RopeStep/6}{0.45*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{1.5*\RopeStep}{\RopeWidth/2}}
     \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint{10*\RopeStep/6}{0.55*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{11*\RopeStep/6}{0.6*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{13.5*\RopeStep/6}{\RopeWidth/2}}
    \setcounter{ropept}{0}
    \pgfcoordinate{lastup-\theropept}{\pgfpoint{-1.5*\RopeStep/6}{-\RopeWidth/2}}
    \pgfcoordinate{rope-auxA-\theropept}{\pgfpoint{13.5*\RopeStep/6}{\RopeWidth/2}}
  }
  \state{cont}[width=\RopeStep]{ 
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{lastup-\theropept}{center}}
     \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint{-5*\RopeStep/6}{-0.6*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{-4*\RopeStep/6}{-0.55*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{-3*\RopeStep/6}{-0.55*\RopeWidth}}
     \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint{-\RopeStep/6}{-0.45*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{\RopeStep/6}{-0.25*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{3*\RopeStep/6}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint{5*\RopeStep/6}{0.25*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{7*\RopeStep/6}{0.45*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{9*\RopeStep/6}{\RopeWidth/2}}
     \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint{10*\RopeStep/6}{0.55*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{11*\RopeStep/6}{0.6*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{13.5*\RopeStep/6}{\RopeWidth/2}}
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{rope-auxA-\theropept}{center}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{9*\RopeStep/6}{\RopeWidth/2}}
    \stepcounter{ropept}
    \pgfcoordinate{lastup-\theropept}{\pgfpoint{-1.5*\RopeStep/6}{-\RopeWidth/2}}
    \pgfcoordinate{rope-auxA-\theropept}{\pgfpoint{13.5*\RopeStep/6}{\RopeWidth/2}}
  }
  \state{final}[width=5pt]
  {
     \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{lastup-\theropept}{center}}
     \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint{-5*\RopeStep/6}{-0.6*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{-4*\RopeStep/6}{-0.55*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{-0.5*\RopeStep}{-0.55*\RopeWidth}}
     \pgfpathcurveto
    {\pgfpoint{-\RopeStep/6}{-0.45*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{\RopeStep/6}{-0.25*\RopeWidth}}
    {\pgfpoint{0.5*\RopeStep}{0pt}}
    \pgfmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
    \xdef\LastRope{\theropept}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=rope]
  \draw[decorate] plot[smooth cycle, fill=yellow, thick] coordinates{ (4.,8.4) (6.5,9.) (8.,9) (9.,8.1) (11.34,6.18) (11,4) (11.3,2.2) (10.2 7,0.7 ) (8. 4,0.14) (6.2,0.29) (4.40,0.51) (3.2,0.29) (1.5,0.34) } ; 
  \typeout{\theropept}
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: feel free to include a rope decoration into your answer to my [arithmetic rope](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452831/representing-an-arithmetic-rope) question if you like...

Comment: @Bart Yes, I'll do. Thanks for your patience. There are still things that I do not understand and within the next week there is no 2h window in which I have time to systematically study what's going on.

Comment: How can I add the [decoration=rope] to the \draw plot so that I get a free curve with this rope pattern?

Comment: @Thumbolt What is a "free" curve?

Comment: Say, \draw plot[smooth cycle, fill=yellow, thick] coordinates{
 (4.,8.4) (6.5,9.) (8.,9) (9.,8.1) (11.34,6.18)  (11,4)  (11.3,2.2)   (10.2 7,0.7 )  (8. 4,0.14)  (6.2,0.29)  (4.40,0.51)   (3.2,0.29)   (1.5,0.34) } ;

Comment: Yes, and the rope looks torn at the sudden turns. Such curvature is there when I draw several ropes randomly arranged.

Comment: @Thumbolt I added a version that does not have gaps. However, it does not really look good either in regions of large curvature. The problem is the decorations add a sequence of small repeating elements which are *straight*. I do not know any reasonable method to overcome this problem.

Comment: @marmot I do not know your answer and I do not know why you changed it. And you do not have to tell me. I always appreciated the time you took and I learned a lot from your work.

Comment: @CampanIgnis Thanks for your kind words. [Given some IMHO inappropriate actions by one of the moderators](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8369/121799) I have no other option than to quit. This makes me all very sad and deleting my answers is absolutely not what I want... I wish there would be a better way of telling the moderator that he has gone too far.

Comment: @marmot You want to spread your accusations against me  (and against the moderator team you say they are not neutral as my "buddies") over the site? Please stay ontopic here, and you can continue discussing on meta if you need.

Comment: @marmot Thank you for your reply. As a non-involved bystander I do not have a deep understanding on these issue. But I do appreciate that you have reedited your post here. It is a great loss if formerly freely accessible knowledge is lost. Due to the language barrier I do not visit TeXWelt.de often but I assume you did some great work over there as well. I hope the problems can be settled satisfactorily for marmot, the moderators, and all bystanders.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Yes, I stand to my statements (I also kept all the emails), and the deletion of my account is scheduled to take place in 21 hours.

Comment: @user121799 That will be a terrible loss.

Comment: @CampanIgnis Thanks for the warm words! I tried to explain things [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8369/121799). Hope to see you on another site in which users are honest, and if one user goes berserk not all involved get suspended.